# Fluent Validation - Single error message for NotEmpty() and NotNull() methods

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation

I am using Fluent Validation to validate event class.

Here is my event class:

```
 public class CardBlockedEvent : Event
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "EventType")]
        public override EventType EventType => EventType.CARD_BLOCK;

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ModifiedByUUID")]
        public string ModifiedByUUID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ModifiedByUserName")]
        public string ModifiedByUserName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Data")]
        public List<CardBlocked> Data { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Messages")]
        public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my fluent validator:

```
public class CardBlockedEventValidator : AbstractValidator<CardBlockedEvent>
    {
        public CardBlockedEventValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.ModifiedByUUID)
                .NotEmpty()
                .NotNull();

        }
    }
```

But I am getting two error message when pass null to "ModifiedByUUID" parameter.

> Modified By UUID' must not be empty.,'Modified By UUID' must not be
>   empty.

Why I am getting two error messages.
How Can I set single message for this check?

Comment: For a string, not empty will fail if the string is null, you don't necessarily need to explicitly define a not null validator. If you want to retain both not null and not empty validators, consider setting cascade on the rule (or FV in general, whatever suits) which allows you to stop on the first error; https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html#setting-the-cascade-mode

Comment: @rgvlee Thanks! Its working fine now.